# Unity 3D. Moving along z axis does not set z value to 0

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just have an object that moves parallel to x axis or z axis, but when it moves along z axis, the z coordinates never is 0. Even if I set it to 0, it just goes really small like e-06. This does not happen when moving along x axis.

I presume it happens because float is not accurate enough, but the strange thing is, this only happens to z coordinate only when it moves along z axis. It does not happen when it moves parrallel to z axis like z = 1.

Is this a know bug? Anyway to go over this?

Comment: Just don't count on float values ever being exact. Anything about your exact setup may affect it.

Comment: @Bart yeah. my programme doesn't need good accuracy, but its inconsistency was just seemed weird to me. only happens to the z axis and only happens when z = "0".

Comment: moved whole programme away from the z axis, and works perfectly well now.